# How to put array values to another array random?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have the array of images with a length of 6 (we call array first).I want to save this 6 values in another array with a length of 12 so that each value of the first array repeated twice in the second array and the values placed in random places of the second array .

For example : first array = {3,4,20,33,1,25}

The second array can be = {4,20,33,1,20,25,25,3,4,1,3,33}

```
public class PlayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static boolean isTheSameOk = true;
final Random rnd = new Random();
int saverandom;
int dontsame = 0 ;
int [] allimages = {R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3, R.drawable.img4, R.drawable.img5,
        R.drawable.img6, R.drawable.img7, R.drawable.img8, R.drawable.img9, R.drawable.img10, R.drawable.img11,
        R.drawable.img12, R.drawable.img13, R.drawable.img14, R.drawable.img15, R.drawable.img16, R.drawable.img17,
        R.drawable.img18, R.drawable.img19, R.drawable.img20, R.drawable.img21, R.drawable.img22, R.drawable.img23,
        R.drawable.img24, R.drawable.img25, R.drawable.img26, R.drawable.img27, R.drawable.img28, R.drawable.img29,
        R.drawable.img30, R.drawable.img31, R.drawable.img32, R.drawable.img33, R.drawable.img34, R.drawable.img35,
        R.drawable.img36, R.drawable.img37, R.drawable.img38, R.drawable.img39, R.drawable.img40};
int [] chooseimages = new int [6];
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);


    //choose 6 image from 40 image we have for putting into buttons
    for(int counter = 0 ; counter<6 ; counter++){
        saverandom = rnd.nextInt(39);

        if(DontSameChoose(allimages[saverandom])){
            chooseimages[counter] = saverandom;
        }else {
            counter--;
        }
    }

    //put the select images in buttons


}
protected boolean DontSameChoose (int imageid){

    for(int c = 0 ; c<6 ; c++){
        if(imageid == chooseimages[c]){
            isTheSameOk = false;
        }
    }
    return isTheSameOk;
}
}
```

the first array is choose images that have the 6 id of the images and i want to save the values in the way i said above in the another array with the lenght of 12 .

Comment: And what you have tried so far ?

Comment: So copy the values twice, to different offsets in the target array, then shuffle the target array.

Comment: What are you stuck on?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Now i have the first array called it in my code chooseimages and it have the values but i dont know exactly how to put the values like i said above ...

Comment: @DanielHernández Done .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you transform your arrays into `ArrayList`, here is a short solution:

```
ArrayList<Integer> secondList = new ArrayList<>(firstList);
secondList.addAll(firstList);
Collections.shuffle(secondList);
```

Comment: Change `a2` to `secondList`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
   HashMap <Integer,Integer> mapa;
            mapa = new HashMap<>();
            int cont=0;
            int arr[] = new int[12];
            int arr2[] = new int[]{3,4,20,33,1,25};
            for(int i=0;i<12;i++){
                arr[i] = (int)Math.random()*100;
            }
            while(true){
                int random = (int)Math.random()*12;

                if(mapa.containsKey(random)){
                }else{
                    mapa.put(random, 1);
                    arr[random] = arr2[cont++];
                }
                if(cont >= 6){
                    break;
                }
}
```